# Add Mouse Wheel event to Excel embedded Chart object

Tags: excel, vba, mouseevent, excel-charts

I'm trying to enhance user interaction with excel embedded chart objects. To be honest, nothing more of what you can currently find every where else, but this doesn't seem so true for excel charts.

In the list of chart's events I can't find the MouseWheel event, so my request is to add/simulate the MouseWheel event to an excel embedded chart object.

I googled around without success, so...
can someone of you point me in the right direction in order to accomplish the below mentioned task?

When I select/activate an embedded chart, the task is stopping the default mouse wheel behaviour (scroll or zoom the worksheet area - depending on the Ctrl key is pressed or not) and resize chart through zooming in/out X,Y axis scales by up/down mouse wheel movement

Please get a look at my other request [[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57915079/convertion-of-mouse-pointer-coordinates-into-data-coordinates-and-graphical-obje)

Comment: I think there is not that event. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137104/zooming-in-using-mouse-wheel

Comment: Yes... just for this reason I'm searching an alternative solution for doing that. The old approach based on window handle is no more possible. Since Excel 2007, the Excel rendering engine has been deeply changed and an embedded chart is now "windowless". An alternative solution will really appreciated